# How can I count exactly how many lowercase characters come after an uppercase character?

Tags: python

For example: "He Is a small man" has 2 lowercase characters that come after an uppercase. I have tried googling but I haven't found anything similar there. I have this code where I'm counting the lowercase and uppercase characters:

```
letters = input("Enter string: ")
count1=0
count2=0
for i in letters:
      if(i.islower()):
            count1=count1+1
      elif(i.isupper()):
            count2=count2+1

print("The number of lowercase characters is:")
print(count1)
print("The number of uppercase characters is:")
print(count2)
```

Comment: Well try coding something and then show us what you have already tried. Btw a piece of code is usually clearer than a text about what it does

Comment: Sorry guys, it's my first time asking a question here haha :) I just edited the code to show you guys what I have already. Hopefully you guys can help me.

Comment: *"He Is a small man" has 2 lowercase characters that come after an uppercase* : Why 2? After the uppercase 'H' there is only 1 lowercase 'e'. Or are you also counting spaces as lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to split the string into substrings that each follow a `<UPPERCASE><not uppercase>` pattern.

For example, the following pattern

```
([A-Z][^A-Z]*)
```

splits your sample string "*He Is a small man*" into the following substrings

```
He 
Is a small man
```

then you can further split each substring into `<UPPERCASE>` and `<not uppercase>`

```
H, e
I, s a small man
```

and then finally get the `len()` of the `<not uppercase>` substring.

Here's a sample code:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile("(([A-Z])([^A-Z]*))")
matches = re.findall(pattern, input("Enter string: "))

for m in matches:
    print(f"substring: {m[0]}")

    uppercase = m[1]
    print(f"uppercase: {uppercase}")

    lowercases = m[2].replace(" ", "")
    num_lowercases = len(lowercases)
    print(f"lowercase chars: {num_lowercases}")
```

That outputs:

```
Enter string: He Is a small man
substring: He 
uppercase: H
lowercase chars: 1
substring: Is a small man
uppercase: I
lowercase chars: 10
```

The matches are retrieved using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), which returns all patterns from the string, as a list of tuples, for example:

```
('He ', 'H', 'e ')

[0]: substring that matches the pattern
[1]: the uppercase character
[2]: the rest of the non-uppercase characters
```

Notice that I added `.replace(" ", "")` to exclude spaces from the count of lowercase characters. If you also want the total count of uppercase and lowercase, you could just track the total similar to your `count1` and `count2` variables:

```py
import re

total_uppercase = 0
total_lowercase = 0

pattern = re.compile("(([A-Z])([^A-Z]*))")
matches = re.findall(pattern, input("Enter string: "))

for m in matches:
    print(f"substring: {m[0]}")

    uppercase = m[1]
    print(f"uppercase: {uppercase}")
    total_uppercase += 1

    lowercases = m[2].replace(" ", "")
    num_lowercases = len(lowercases)
    print(f"lowercase chars: {num_lowercases}")
    total_lowercase += num_lowercases

print(f"total uppercase: {total_uppercase}")
print(f"total lowercase: {total_lowercase}")
```

which outputs:

```
Enter string: He Is a small man
...
total uppercase: 2
total lowercase: 11
```